# How to use Tor without browser in python?

Tags: python, windows, tor, socks

I have a client raw socket app that I want to connect to a server on a .onion address. Everything is working fine, except that I have to open Tor Browser in order to connect to the server via client script. I think this happens because tor opens when Tor Browser starts. I tried to start tor without browser using tor.exe -f "torrc-defaults path". In task manager, it seems like tor is running but my client script give me an error like tor is not open. So How do I connect to Tor without having Tor installed in my pc?
Here is my client error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client_onion.py", line 10, in <module>
    s.connect((onion_address,port))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 96, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 813, in connect
    negotiate(self, dest_addr, dest_port)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 477, in _negotiate_SOCKS5
    CONNECT, dest_addr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 552, in _SOCKS5_request
    raise SOCKS5Error("{0:#04x}: {1}".format(status, error))
socks.SOCKS5Error: 0x04: Host unreachable
```

Comment: Check out the Tor Expert Bundle for Windows at https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en   This is what you should be using instead of the browser.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

Use ["Expert Bundle"](https://www.torproject.org/download/tor/) to get the Tor binary without any browser.The expert bundle connects to the Tor network and allows you to make SOCKS5 connections and control port connections. You can control everything it does via the config file or  through a 'Tor controller'.
You can download it from [Download](https://www.torproject.org/download/tor/) | [Mirror 1](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/Tor.shtml)